# Enumerate a key's subkeys and their value/data? C++

Tags: winapi

I have been trying to get the code below to read the "SOFTWARE" registry key, enumerate its subkeys such as "SOFTWARE\XXXX" then read all key names and data within each subkey (not all subkeys, just 1 level below Software). I also want to use strstr when a specific string is found, to delete the key. I have a long way to go. I'm a nooblet as well so please include as much detail as possible :) The code will currently enumerate the subkeys and tell the names of each, but not display the values or data for them.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383

using namespace std;

void QueryKey(HKEY hKey)
{
    TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
    DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
    TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name 
    DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
    DWORD    cSubKeys = 0;               // number of subkeys 
    DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
    DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
    DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
    DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
    DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
    DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

    DWORD i, retCode;

    TCHAR achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
    DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

    // Get the class name and the value count. 
    retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
        hKey,                    // key handle 
        achClass,                // buffer for class name 
        &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
        NULL,                    // reserved 
        &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
        &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
        &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
        &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
        &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
        &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
        &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

    // Enumerate the subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.

    if (cSubKeys)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of subkeys: %d\n", cSubKeys);

        for (i = 0; i<cSubKeys; i++)
        {
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
            retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i, achKey, &cbName, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ftLastWriteTime);
            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), i + 1, achKey);
            }
        }
    }

    // Enumerate the key values. 

    BYTE* buffer = new BYTE[cbMaxValueData];
    ZeroMemory(buffer, cbMaxValueData);

    if (cValues)
    {
        for (i = 0, retCode = ERROR_SUCCESS; i<cValues; i++)
        {
            cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
            achValue[0] = '\0';
            retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, achValue, &cchValue, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                DWORD lpData = cbMaxValueData;
                buffer[0] = '\0';
                LONG dwRes = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, achValue, 0, NULL, buffer, &lpData);
                _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s : %s\n"), i + 1, achValue, buffer);
            }
        }
    }
    delete[] buffer;
}

int RegKeyCount = 0;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HKEY hTestKey;
    const char* subkey = "SOFTWARE\\";

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        QueryKey(hTestKey);
        RegCloseKey(hTestKey);
        cin.get();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is the problem you are currently having with this code?  Don't just throw code around, not explain what is happening with it, and expect people to figure it out.  Please be more specific.

Comment: The code will currently enumerate the subkeys and tell the names of each, but not display the values or data for them. Yes, I realized that after posting and already did edit that in.

Comment: And what have you done so far to try to debug it yourself to figure out why it is not enumerating the key values?  This is a Q&A site, we are here to answer specific questions, not do the work for you.

Comment: I've tried to use regenumvalue after if (cSubKeys). Just not sure where to start.

Comment: Well, you are only enumerating the subkeys and values underneath the `SOFTWARE` key itself.  That key does not have any values of its own, only subkeys. If you want to enumerate all subkeys, and their subkeys, and their subkeys, and so on, you need to call `QueryKey()` recursively, where it calls `RegOpenKeyEx()` and `QueryKey()` on each subkey found, then it will enumerate the subkeys calling `RegOpenKeyEx()` and `QueryKey()` on each of them, and so on. Have you ever worked with a recursive function before (a function that calls itself)?

Comment: Beautiful. I got it working, still needs some testing. Thanks for the tips! I'll post back with the updated code, and what I had to do to recursively QueryKey()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scan through the entire `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE` tree, or even just a portion of it, you need to write `QueryKey()` to run recursively.  To scan a portion of the tree, you can give `QueryKey()` an input parameter specifying the desired recursion depth.

Also, since you are using C++, you should use C++ containers, like `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;

// RecursiveDepth:
// < 0: recurse the whole tree below hKey
// = 0: do not recurse the tree
// > 0: recurse specified levels below hKey
//
void QueryKey(HKEY hKey, int RecursiveDepth = -1)
{
    TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
    DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
    TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name 
    DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
    DWORD    cSubKeys = 0;               // number of subkeys
    DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
    DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
    DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
    DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
    DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
    DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

    DWORD i;
    LONG retCode;

    TCHAR achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
    DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

    // Get the class name and the value count. 
    retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
        hKey,                    // key handle 
        achClass,                // buffer for class name 
        &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
        NULL,                    // reserved 
        &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
        &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
        &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
        &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
        &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
        &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
        &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
        &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

    if (retCode != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        return;

    // Enumerate the key values. 

    if (cValues)
    {
        printf("\nNumber of values: %u\n", cValues);

        std::vector<BYTE> buffer(cbMaxValueData+1);

        for (i = 0; i < cValues; ++i)
        {
            cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;
            retCode = RegEnumValue(hKey, i, achValue, &cchValue, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                DWORD lpData = cbMaxValueData;
                retCode = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, achValue, 0, NULL, &buffer[0], &lpData);
                if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                    _tprintf(TEXT("(%u) %s : %.*s\n"), i + 1, achValue, lpData, &buffer[0]);
            }
        }
    }

    // Enumerate the subkeys.

    if ((cSubKeys) && (RecursiveDepth != 0))
    {
        printf("\nNumber of subkeys: %d\n", cSubKeys);

        int NextDepth = RecursiveDepth;
        if (NextDepth > 0) --NextDepth;

        std::vector<tstring> vecKeys;
        vecKeys.reserve(cSubKeys);

        for (i = 0; i < cSubKeys; ++i)
        {
            cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
            retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(hKey, i, achKey, &cbName, NULL, NULL, NULL, &ftLastWriteTime);
            if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                _tprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), i + 1, achKey);
                vecKeys.push_back(achKey);
            }
        }

        for (std::vector<tstring>::iterator iter = vecKeys.begin(), end = vecKeys.end(); iter != end; ++iter)
        {
            HKEY hTestKey;
            if (RegOpenKeyEx(hKey, iter->c_str(), 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                QueryKey(hTestKey, NextDepth);
                RegCloseKey(hTestKey);
            } 
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const TCHAR *subkey = TEXT("SOFTWARE\\");
    HKEY hTestKey;

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, subkey, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hTestKey) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        QueryKey(hTestKey, 1);
        RegCloseKey(hTestKey);
    }

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remy, thank you! This is currently what I had going. How can I change it so the loop for QueryKey(hTestKey); only looks at 1 level below SOFTWARE and doesn't try to enumerate any subkeys below that? For example: HKCU\Software\XXXX and no keys like HKCU\Software\XXXX\XXXX?

Comment: You will have to pass a parameter to `QueryKey()` specifying the desired depth, and then each recursive call can decrement the value until it reaches 0.  I have updated my example.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that could be used. It's not working though. I am only trying to pull the value names and data of 1 subkey deep in software. (I don't need the subkey names, only the value names and data for these subkeys). You've helped me a lot, rather advanced for me so you have talent!

Comment: I made a small edit to my example. If it is still not working, you will have to be more specific about what is not working correctly. I have not actually run this code yet.

Comment: Remy, you did it.*dances* What did you fix?

Comment: You can look at the details of the last edit to see a diff between it and the previous edit.

Comment: @JesseBropez If your question has been answered you can click the check mark to accept the answer.